# jwplayer total videos view count

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jwplayer

I have used jwplayer plugin for displaying videos on page, i want to get the total number of count when any user see the video. I have searched about this, but did not find that can help me to figure out the problem. I have used the (onPlay) event but it only fire when user play the video and pause the video. can anyone help me to figure out this problem.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var count= 1;
     jwplayer().onPlay(function(){
      var jwcount = count++;
     alert(jwcount);

     });

    });
    <script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use `jwplayer` to play the videos stored at your own server, there's no need to implement some external solution: the server itself will log each request, you just have to parse the logfiles.

Comment: Are you using JW5 or JW6?

Comment: I am using JW6 player for this